# Problema con php en header con formulario

Tags: php, html

Quería si saber si alguien me podia dar una mano con este formulario que básicamente cuando no ingresa los campos requeridos refresca en el mismo html. El tema que siempre recibo este error

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/redirigitalmismo.php:6)
>   in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/redirigitalmismo.php on line 16

y no se como solucionarlo.Supuestamente es porque estoy enviando información antes que el header. Muchas gracias

```
    <?php
  ob_start();
?>

<?php
$errores = array();
if($_POST){
  if(!trim($_POST['nombre'])) {
  $errores['nombre'] = 'Debe ingresar un nombre';
  }
  if(!trim($_POST['email'])) {
  $errores['email'] = 'Debes ingresar un mail';
  }
  if(!$errores) {
  header('Location: http://www.google.com');
  exit();
    }
};
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form  action=""  name="formulario" method="POST">
      <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" maxlength="30" onfocus="fondoColor(this)" placeholder="Tu nombre">
      <?php if(isset($errores['nombre'])) { echo '<div>No pusiste Nombre</div>'; } ?>
      <br>
      <input type="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="Tu Mail">
      <?php if(isset($errores['email'])) { echo '<div>No ingresaste Mail</div>'; } ?>
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="sexo" id="Hombre"value="Hombre"> Hombre
      <input type="radio" name="sexo" id="Mujer"value="Mujer"> Mujer
      <br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="terminos[]" id="terminos" value="uno" > Terminos y condiciones
      <br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="terminos[]" id="terminos"  value="dos"> Mas terminos y condiciones
      <br>
      <input type="submit" name="btn" value="Enviar" id="btn">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
<?php
  ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: Coloca el error completo, para saber en que linea o  que archivo esta generando el error.

Comment: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/redirigitalmismo.php:6) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/redirigitalmismo.php on line 16

Comment: El código que colocas es el código de tu archivo redirigitalmismo.php?

Comment: SI!! es el mismo archivo! modifique lo del array arriba y sigue tirando 
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/redirigitalmismo.php:6) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/redirigitalmismo.php on line 16

Comment: Viste! un Bajon! php  7.0.8

Comment: @HernanBessera Si tenés algún espacio o cualquier otro caracter antes de abrir el primer `<?php`, deberías eliminarlo. El error dice que estás enviando el cuerpo del HTML **antes** del encabezado... `<?php` debería **aparecer como el primer caracter** de tu script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya encontre el error! No me daba cuenta porque directamente iba al archivo. El mamp automaticamente se refresca sin parar(ya probe re instalarlo) y entonces no me deja hacer NADA. Por ende seguramente tenia problemas en mi php. Ahora voy a contacar a soporte MAMP. MUCHAS GRACIAS A TODOS POR LA AYUDA

Comment: Por favor, postea la respuesta y márcala como respondida.

Answer (score 0):

Ocurre que al principio no estas condicionado, esta declarando que el valor de nombre y email es igual a lo que esta entre las comillas:

```
<?php
$errores = [];
if($_POST){
if(!trim($_POST['nombre'])) {
$errores['nombre'] = 'Debe ingresar un nombre';
}
if(!trim($_POST['email'])) {
$errores['email'] = 'Debes ingresar un mail';
}
if(!$errores) {
header('Location: http://www.google.com');
exit();
}
};
?>
```

Agrega el error del otro archivo que mencionas.

Por otra parte el array se deberá declarar con la sintaxis:

```
$errores = array();
```

El error se origina por la sintaxis de la cabezera, declara el html antes, ya que lo estas modificando mas adelante y eso no es funcional

Quedaria asi:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
$errores = array();
if($_POST){
if(!trim($_POST['nombre'])) {
   $errores['nombre'] = 'Debe ingresar un nombre';
}
if(!trim($_POST['email'])) {
$errores['email'] = 'Debes ingresar un mail';
} 
if(!$errores) {
 header('Location: http://www.google.com');
exit();
}
};
?>

<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<form  action=""  name="formulario" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" maxlength="30"   onfocus="fondoColor(this)" placeholder="Tu nombre">
  <?php if(isset($errores['nombre'])) { echo '<div>No pusiste Nombre</div>';     } ?>
  <br>
  <input type="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="Tu Mail">
  <?php if(isset($errores['email'])) { echo '<div>No ingresaste Mail</div>'; } ?>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="sexo" id="Hombre"value="Hombre"> Hombre
  <input type="radio" name="sexo" id="Mujer"value="Mujer"> Mujer
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="terminos[]" id="terminos" value="uno" > Terminos y condiciones
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="terminos[]" id="terminos"  value="dos"> Mas terminos y condiciones
  <br>
  <input type="submit" name="btn" value="Enviar" id="btn">
</form>
```

Te invito a revisar esta pagina: 
http://librosweb.es/foro/pregunta/128/como-solucionar-el-problema-headers-already-sent-de-php/

Comment: El otro archivo es el mismo!

Comment: Modifique eso mismo y sigue tirando 

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/redirigitalmismo.php:6) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/redirigitalmismo.php on line 16

Comment: prueba corregir el array, a mi me sirve como esta, no marca errores, pero no se donde esta el php que tiene el action para que envie eso

Comment: La declaración del array a partir de php 5.4 es correcta con `[]`, por ende no *deberá* declararse de esa forma, a menos que se use una versión de php inferior a la mencionada. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: ok agendado!!! Igualmente sigue sin andar

Comment: agendado?, pues en mi pc tengo la ultima version del xampp no se que php usara pero me marcaba error con los corchetes, ya queda de parte del usuario que pregutna cambiar eso

Comment: Hernan, como te lo acabo de publicar funciona normal en mi computador

Comment: Puedes revisar la documentación de php @VictorAlejandroAlvaradoVilo

Comment: claro que lo hare :) gracias xD

Comment: Supongo que es para ahorrar problemas para los que venimos de JS en PHP. jajaja 
Bueno gente no molesto mas! no se que sera!

Comment: comprueba tu instalacion de php, y la que tiene tu amigo. has guardado el archivo, los has cerrado y ejecutado de nuevo?, me ha pasado

Comment: por cierto, mi php segun es 7.0.4

Answer (score 0):

Intenta hacer uso de esto:

```
// antes de cualquier línea de código html o php:
<?php
  ob_start();
?>

// al final del documento:

<?php
  ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: Si tambien lo tuve en cuenta! pero salta esto 
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/redirigitalmismo.php:7) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/redirigitalmismo.php on line 21

Comment: Intenta eliminar el salto de linea y espacio en blanco que existe entre el cierre php `?>` y `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: Ahi lo hice y sigue el error. Capaz es mi servidor o mi cache!

Comment: Elimina la cache y las cookies del navegador, realmente no se que más puede ser la causa, puede ser a nivel de servidor. Probé tu codigo en phpfiddle y corre sin ningun problema.

Comment: ok gracias ahi voy a intentar! Son frecuentes estos errores con php?

Comment: Realmente ocurren por descuidos al dejar espacios en blanco, o por usar funciones que modifican los headers, no son muy frecuentes, en xampp no he obtenido ningun error de este tipo, puede ser por alguna configuracion de wamp, intenta probar tu código en XAMPP o en linux (LAMP).

Comment: actualmente estoy usando mamp! voy a probar lo raro, es que mi compañero tiene mamp y a el no le tira error! Debe ser problema de mi maquina

Answer (score -2):

Intenta agregando primero el **HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
$errores = [];
bla, bla, bla ...
```

Comment: Sigue igual! Lo raro es que este archivo mismo se lo pase a un compañero y a el le anda y a mi NO

Comment: mm ok entonces es tema de configuración de tu PHP, prueba tu proyecto en tu servidor productivo.